# Do Firebase Functions suffer performance losses with Express?

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to both Express and Firebase, but I was under the impression that the key benefits of functions is load balancing and providing each function with as much bandwidth as it needs.

Meanwhile whenever I look for way to combine Firebase functions with Express, it's always a single Express app being bound to a single function.

Wouldn't that be a major performance issue since a single function is handling all of your api requests? Would it be better to create a function for each endpoint or at least groups of them? Or is creating so many Express instances an even worse idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each function invocation runs completely isolated in its own server instance.  It doesn't matter how many functions you have defined in your project, as each invocation of each function are all fully independent of each other.  Also, within one server instance, each function invocation (no matter which route is being invoked) is handled in serial, as you would expect from node.  Performance is never the issue in situations like this, except where your code is being inefficient.  Since you haven't said what your code is doing, there's no way to make any statements about its actual performance in Cloud Functions.

The only real limitation is scaling.  Each function can scale up to 1000 concurrent instances maximum.  So if you have an express app behind a single function serving all your requests, then that app will scale up to 1000.  If you have two apps behind two functions, then each of those two functions can scale up to 1000, for a total of 2000.

If you think this limit of 1000 concurrent instances is problematic, you might be overestimating the load on your project.  Or, you might be doing way too much work in one function invocation.  If this is really the case, Cloud Functions is not the best tool for you, and you should exerting more control over your environment with App Engine or Compute Engine.